# System.out.Println being skipped

Tags: java

I am supposed to be making a simple rock paper scissors code but most of my println's aren't working. I tried adding another one to see if it was just my variable assignment for choose and rand but it doesn't output anything either. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project4 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random in = new Random();
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select one of [R/P/S]: ");
    String choice = key.nextLine();
    int rand = in.nextInt(3) + 1;
    int choose = 0;
    if (choice.equals("r") || choice.equals("R")) {
      choose = 1;
      System.out.println("You chose Rock");
    } else {
      if (choice.equals("P") || choice.equals("p")) {
        choose = 2;
        System.out.println("You chose Paper");
      } else {
        if (choice.equals("s") || choice.equals("S")) {
          choose = 3;
          System.out.println("You chose Scissors");
        }
      }
      System.out.println("rand= " + rand + "choose =" + choose);
      System.out.flush();
    }
    if (rand == 1) {
      System.out.println("I chose Rock");
    } else {
      if (rand == 2) {
        System.out.println("I chose Paper");
      } else {
        System.out.println("I chose Scissors");
      }

      if (choose == rand) {
        System.out.println("Its a Tie!");
      } else {
        if (choose == 1 && rand == 2) {
          System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, You lose!");
        } else {
          if (choose == 1 && rand == 3) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, You win!");
          } else {
            if (choose == 2 && rand == 1) {
              System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, You win!");
            } else {
              if (choose == 2 && rand == 3) {
                System.out.println("Scissors beats Paper, You lose!");
              } else {
                if (choose == 3 && rand == 1) {
                  System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, You lose!");
                } else {
                  System.out.println("Scissors beats Paper, You win!");
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: a first step should allways, don´t start doubting java code wont run. It will most most most likely not skip code, but rather doubt your own logic. Also what doesn´t print? for me it works

Comment: after it says which one you choose and before it says what it chose, it should output what the variables rand and choose have as values. then any of the lines where it says you win or you lose or Its a Tie! aren't outputting for me in eclipse.

Comment: There are *way* too many `{}`s here for you not to format this cleanly; fix it please (-1).

Comment: This does also work. Intend your code and you might notice why it doesn´t allways print it.

Comment: It works also for me

Comment: I've been java coding for a month I don't know how to make it cleaner.

Comment: Align your `{}`s and indentations according to your nesting; it's that simple. Use Java conventions and keep it consistent.

Comment: or if you are using eclispe for example press `ctrl + f` and it will automatically intend the code into a readable format for you

Comment: Please use `else if (condition){` instead of `else{ if(condition){`! you save tabs and brackets, at least in your program it would make sense!

Comment: ...or with Intellij `ctl+alt+l` but I suggest you learn and apply it yourself and use that as a convenience not as a crutch.

Comment: Okay after cleaning up the brackets as suggested everything works thank you guys!

Comment: The line `System.out.println("rand= " + rand + "choose =" + choose);` is inside the else part if your indentation is to be trusted. So apparaently this printout does not happen if user chooses rock (r), but if it does if s/he chooses paper or scissors.

Answer (score 0):

Your System.out.println are being skipped because you have put some of them inside the 'else' conditions. Due to this when the 'IF' condition is true the else block is skipped and so is the sysout's. The below code should work!

Also I would suggest using else-if in place of the nested-if conditions as it make is more readable and less error prone.

```
package project4;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class project4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random in = new Random();
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select one of [R/P/S]: ");
    String choice = key.nextLine();
    int rand = in.nextInt(3) + 1;
    int choose = 0;
    if (choice.equals("r") || choice.equals("R")) {
        choose = 1;
        System.out.println("You chose Rock");
    } else {
        if (choice.equals("P") || choice.equals("p")) {
            choose = 2;
            System.out.println("You chose Paper");
        } else {
            if (choice.equals("s") || choice.equals("S")) {
                choose = 3;
                System.out.println("You chose Scissors");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("rand= " + rand + "choose =" + choose);
    System.out.flush();
    if (rand == 1) {
        System.out.println("I chose Rock");
    } else {
        if (rand == 2) {
            System.out.println("I chose Paper");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I chose Scissors");
        }
    }

    if (choose == rand) {
        System.out.println("Its a Tie!");
    } else {
        if (choose == 1 && rand == 2) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, You lose!");
        } else {
            if (choose == 1 && rand == 3) {
                System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, You win!");
            } else {
                if (choose == 2 && rand == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, You win!");
                } else {
                    if (choose == 2 && rand == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Scissors beats Paper, You lose!");
                    } else {
                        if (choose == 3 && rand == 1) {
                            System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, You lose!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Scissors beats Paper, You win!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}